# create a service for running a executable jar with out any 3rd party

Tags: windows

I have spring boot executable jar file which can run into any command prompt by calling java -jar filename.jar.

I want to create a service with out downloading any external libraries for the above code snippet.

Help me if there is a strait forward way.

Comment: What OS? What version?

Comment: Its windows 10 pro

Answer (score 2):

Simple (and recommended): Download and use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc). Or use SC to create a service without downloads.

**Using SC to create a service from command line**

The SC command communicates with the Windows Service Controller and installed services. When used with its create command option, you can use it to create a Windows service under which your binary will run. But the binary *must* be created for this ([so Windows knows it will respect API calls and gives correct status information](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)).

The SC Create command uses the following format:

```
sc create serviceName binpath="path\to\java.exe path\to\.jar" optionName= optionValue...
```

where:

- `create` is the command to be run by SC (this command name is mandatory to create a service).
- `serviceName` is the name of the Windows service to be created. This is the name given to the service key in the registry. Note that this name is different from the display name.
- `binpath` is the (mandatory) parameter that specifies the path to the Win32/x64 binary. Note that a space *must* be used between the binpath parameter and its argument. You should also use double quotes around the argument.
- `optionName` specifies optional parameters, which are described [in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create)